# How can i add property dynamically to a QML element?

Tags: qml

I want to add properties dynamically to a QML element:

```
Item {
 id: dynamicProperty;
 property int first;


 Component.onCompleted: {
  /* once this block of code is executed, i want to add
     property int second; property bool third; property variant fourth;
  */
 }

}
```

Is there any way to accomplish the above task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think QML was designed to support dynamic property creation.

Depending on your use-case this could be worked around with "script instances" (I made up the term). Basically each QML Component instantiation that import script which doesn't have `.pragma library` statement will work with its own copy of globals declared in the script.

For example you can look at PageStack (qt-components) [code](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-components/qt-components/blobs/master/src/meego/PageStack.qml).

There is `import "PageStack.js" as Engine` statement, and it later referred to call functions that uses global variables like if it was instance variables.

If you looking for a way to add members to your QML Component and don't need property change notifications, "script instances" would do just fine.

Answer (score 13):

On the one hand: I don't see, why anyone would want to do this, as it is completely non-declarative. However, as QML extends JavaScript, and latter is a prototyping-language, **yes, you can** do it.

On the how-to, I reccomend to read the JS-Documentation on [how to define properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). However I wrote a short example, to demonstrate the use of it.

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: console.log(rect.newProp)
}

Rectangle {
    id: rect
    width: 50
    height: 50
    x: 50
    y: 50
    color: 'green'

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: { var obj = Object.defineProperty(rect, 'newProp',
                                                     {
                                                         enumerable: false,
                                                         configurable: false,
                                                         writable: false,
                                                         value: '50'
                                                     })}
    }
}
```

On the first click on the background, 'undefined' will be printed. After clicking on the rectangle, this will change to '50'.

Comment: [English version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) of the useful link above about defining properties.

Comment: Is assigning rect.newProp = xxx supposed to work, after creating it via defineProperty?

Comment: No, the feature is not completely implemented in QML. If you want to change the value, you always need to set it via the `defineProperty` function. To make that clear: This property is not equivalent to a QML property. I think this comes in part, as the `descriptor` is not entirely evaluated. It seems like `enumerable`, `writable`, `setter` and `getter` are ignored. Therefore I usually added a small function `setDynProp(prop, value)` to my objects - in the very rare cases where I actually need this.

Comment: Afore mentioned function might look like this: `Object.defineProperty(rootWindow, 'setDynProp', { value: function(prop, value) { Object.defineProperty(rootWindow, prop, { value: value }) } } )` --- rootWindow is the object I add this function too. So to call it you'll use `rootWindow.setDynProp('newProp', 42)`.

Comment: If you alter a regular JS object (like: `property var myObj: ({})`) you can also use the setters and getters defined in the descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can do it like this:

```
Item {
    id: dynamicProperty;
    property int first;
    property var extraData;

    Component.onCompleted: {
        /* once this block of code is executed, i want to add
           property int second; property bool third; property variant fourth;
        */
        var data;
        data["second"] = 0;
        data["third"] = false;
        ...
        extraData = data;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For most qml items/objects they inherit QtObject, which is QObject internally.

You want to create static QML singleton in C++(https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html)
that implements a function

```cpp
Q_INVOKABLE
void SetProperty(QObject *object, QString property, QVariant value) 
{ 
    object->setProperty(property, value); 
}
```

and call it at least once.
This will create a full-featured qobject/qml property you can use as usual anywhere in qt/qml.

Answer (score -4):

I don't be sure if can add dynamic properties to qml object, buy one form most easy is disable, hide or change properties with if for example:

```
if(manual==true)
{
    icon.visible=true
}
else {
    icon.visible=false
}
```

or you can create dynamic components of your item or change the view with loader element.

Comment: This is not at all an answer to the question... Setting a component to be invisible, doesn't supply an ability to add properties to a component...