# QML - Capture all UI events of children objects

Tags: qt, events, qml, listener

In my QML project, I need an object to capture all the UI events of its children objects. So, if any of its children register a click or something, the parent object needs to know about it. The issue here is that all of the children objects are pre-defined classes such as MyButton or MyComboBox. These classes all have defined MouseAreas and onClicked() functions that can't be overridden. Therefore, I need the parent object to capture all the events of its children WITHOUT modifying the MouseAreas of the children. Please let me know the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: Do you need to know **which** `MouseArea` was clicked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can crawl the object tree, connecting a function to every `onClicked`-signal.

For this we need three parts:

- The signal that shall be connected
- The function that does the crawling
- A function that creates another function to call the signal with custom arguments.

I chose, that my signal shall have to arguments: `sender` and `arguments`. Sender is the object, that I clicked on, and `arguments` are the arguments of the `clicked`-signal of the clicked object. This is empty for `QtQuick.Controls 2.x Button`s and contains one entry (`mouse`) for `MouseArea`s.

```
signal somethingWasClicked(var sender, var arguments)
```

As this signal has not the same signature as `clicked` for every clickable object, we can't connect it directly to this signal. We need a intermediary function that calls the signal for us, has the needed arguments in it's scope and has no arguments. We need to build this dynamically for each object we spy on.

```
function createSpyFunction(object) {
    return function() { somethingWasClicked(object, arguments) }
}
```

And lastly for the crawl-function. We need to store the function we create somewhere. For this I utilize the fact that all `QtObject`s are JS-Objects in some sense, so I can use `Object.defineProperty` [to dynamically add JS-properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564289/how-can-i-add-property-dynamically-to-a-qml-element/40124978#40124978) to them. Here I can store our function, without the need of modyfing the sourcecode of the components them selves.
After creating this function, I `connect` it to the `onClicked`-handler.

```
function crawlChildren(obj) {
    if (obj.onClicked) {
        Object.defineProperty(obj, '__clickedFunction', { value: createSpyFunction(obj) })
        obj.onClicked.connect(obj.__clickedFunction)
    }
    if (obj.children) {
        var i = 0
        for (; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
            crawlChildren(obj.children[i])
        }
    }
}
```

This function I finally call in

```
Component.onCompleted: crawlObj(this.contentItem)
```

of the root `ApplicationWindow` of my programm.

---

As I only call it in the `Component.onCompleted`-handler, objects that will be added after this, won't be spied uppon. To change this, we will also need to spy on `onChildrenChanged`, and crawl the newly added objects as well. The process there is almost similar, so this is left as an exercise to the user, or might be subject to a new question.

Comment: Yup this did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to overlay your items with a `MouseArea`. In the event handlers you can check the position and call the event handlers of the underlying items.

```
Item {
  MyButton { id: mybutton
      /* set the anchors */
  }
  MyMouseComboBox { id: myMouseComboBox 
     /* set the anchors */
  }

  MouseArea {
     anchros.fill: parent
     onClicked: {
         // mouse.accepted = false
         // Check whether clicked point is within mybutton
         //   on true, call mybutton.doSomething()
         //   or call mybotton.onPressed(mouse)
     }
}
```

Comment: Then you can't handle the `onPressed`-handler in any of the other `MouseArea`s

Comment: No. It is possible to call the handler by invoke of `mybutton.onPressed(mouse)`

Comment: Yeah, so you need to find your way through the object tree to find all the  `MouseArea`s where their layer is unknown.

Comment: The OP wrote about usage of custom components. So I assume he knows which components are in use and where the position is. Otherwise another solution is necessary.

Comment: If so, he could just handle the events directly